# Sample data for Magento

Tags: magento2

I had installed Magento 2.3 without sample data , but i need sample data for some reasons.

Is there any way to get the sample data alone instead of re-dwonloading magento setup with sample data?

Answer (score 1):

Use command

> php bin/magento sampledata:deploy

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways how you can do this (Install using Composer
or by cloning repositories) which are documented here

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/install/sample-data-after-magento.html